# How to parse a date string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a date string with this format

```
2016-08-12T15:22:43.698Z
```

how can I  parse it to obtain a resulting string that looks like

```
Aug 12, 2016 5:22 PM
```

Is there libraries/component that could facilitate such operation or shall I do it manually by coping each part of the String?

Comment: *"Is there libraries..."* ... a simple web search would have given you numerous solutions

Comment: I didn't found anything :/

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You didn't find anything?  Frankly, that is not believable.

Comment: What is this format? what is :43.698Z? it#s not a timestamp!!

Comment: Have a look. [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var date = new moment('2016-08-12T15:22:43.698Z');
console.log(date.format('MMM DD, YYYY h:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com), and format the moment obj as your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is in the ISO standard format, which it looks like it is, you can use `Date.parse()` or `new Date()` to turn the value into a Date object. With a `Date`, you can call `toString()` or `toLocaleString()` to get the date formatted in local time.

If you are targeting modern JavaScript environments, `Intl.DateTimeFormat` provides a very complete API for formatting the date in different locales.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat